# PostgreSQL execute custom queries from string

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a set of functions for a PostgreSQL database I have, and I am facing this problem. What I am trying to do is to create a function, which takes as a parameter the name of his column a user wants to change, and the new value they wish to insert.

I thought that the simplest way would be to create the queries as strings internally and execute them (sql injections are not of concern right now).
Searching a bit, I tried to use the EXECUTE command, with no success. Any arrangement of the queries I tried did not work, with or without SET, and even a super simple query shows a syntax error, inside the function code or in the pgadmin sql editor:

```
EXECUTE "SELECT * FROM user_data.users;";  
ERROR:  prepared statement "SELECT * FROM user_data.users;" does not exist
********** Error **********

ERROR: prepared statement "SELECT * FROM user_data.users;" does not exist
SQL state: 26000
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: `EXECUTE` has a different meaning in plain SQL (such as would be run from pgAdmin) and "pl/pgsql" (the language commonly used for functions). If you post the full function that failed ([edit] it into the question), we can be sure, but my guess is you declared it `language sql` not `language plpgsql`. See  docs: [SQL EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-execute.html), [pl/PgSQL EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Comment: You have to use a `DO` block or function.

Comment: I have not replied because I have not tested these yet, I will get back to you shortly.

Answer (score 0):

To alter a column name you could use a function like this.

It takes the table name, column name, and new column name.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_t regclass, _ocn text, _ncn text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE '|| _t ||'   
            RENAME COLUMN '|| quote_ident(_ocn) ||' TO '|| quote_ident(_ncn) ||'';
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To alter the type is a bit more work and may add to the server overheads.

Lets use this table as an example

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (id serial primary key, name text);
```

Ref [Postgresql Type Conversion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/typeconv.html)

> In many cases a user does not need to understand the details of the
>   type conversion mechanism. However, implicit conversions done by
>   PostgreSQL can affect the results of a query. When necessary, these
>   results can be tailored by using explicit type conversion.

Firstly we would have to get the column data type(s) from the information [The Information Schema Ref postgresql 9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/infoschema-columns.html)

```
select data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'foobar' and column_name = 'name';
```

We could cast types as mentioned in [type conversion::Table 8-1. Data Types Ref Postgresql 9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/typeconv.html)

ALTER TABLE foobar ALTER COLUMN name TYPE varchar(20) USING name::text;

I hope this helps

Comment: Indeed, the EXECUTE ccommand could only work right in a pgsqls function, and not for sql, as mentioned in the comments above. I did not want to alter the table, I wanted the user to be able to specify WHAT to change by name, alongside the new value. Should I post that as an answer?